# Sending mail from java servlet fails authentication

Tags: centos7, exim, smtp-auth, tomcat9

Centos7, tomcat 9, Exim 4.94

Moved all my tomcat apps from centos6 to centos7 server.  Tomcat version is 9 and was the same on both servers.

I send email from one of the java apps.

```
public void sendEmail(String toAddress,
        String subject, String message) throws AddressException,
        MessagingException {

    // sets SMTP server properties
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
    properties.put("mail.smtp.port", port);
    properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "false");

    // creates a new session with an authenticator
    Authenticator auth = new Authenticator() {
        @Override
        public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(user, pass);
        }
    };

    Session session = Session.getInstance(properties, auth);

    // creates a new e-mail message
    Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);

    msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(user));
    InternetAddress[] toAddresses = { new InternetAddress(toAddress) };
    msg.setReplyTo(new javax.mail.Address[] {new javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress(replyTo)});
    msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddresses);
    msg.setSubject(subject);
    msg.setSentDate(new Date());
    msg.setText(message);

    // sends the e-mail
    Transport.send(msg); 
}
```

the variables host = my IP, port = 25

sending from the commandline works fine

mail -s "Test Subject" scott@myaddress.com < /dev/null

sending from the servlet I get this error in catalina.out

```
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535 Incorrect authentication data
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport$Authenticator.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:826)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:761)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:685)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:317)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:125)
at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:194)
at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
at util.EmailUtility.sendEmail(EmailUtility.java:86)
```

The last line util.EmailUtility.sendEmail(EmailUtility.java:86) is the call to the function above.

I'm using sendmail as it was setup on this server.

edit 1.

I set the session.setDebug(true) in the java app function sendEmail above and now I see this in catalina.out

```
DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.4.7
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "68.169.63.242", port 25, isSSL false
220 www.mbepapers.org ESMTP Exim 4.94 Wed, 15 Jul 2020 14:27:07 -0400
DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "68.169.63.242", port: 25

EHLO www.mbepapers.org
250-www.mbepapers.org Hello mbepapers.org [68.169.63.242]
250-SIZE 52428800
250-8BITMIME
250-PIPELINING
250-X_PIPE_CONNECT
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN CRAM-MD5
250-CHUNKING
250-STARTTLS
250 HELP
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "52428800"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "PIPELINING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "X_PIPE_CONNECT", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "AUTH", arg "PLAIN LOGIN CRAM-MD5"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "CHUNKING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "STARTTLS", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "HELP", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Attempt to authenticate using mechanisms: LOGIN PLAIN    DIGEST-MD5 NTLM 
DEBUG SMTP: AUTH LOGIN command trace suppressed
DEBUG SMTP: AUTH LOGIN failed
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535 Incorrect authentication data
```

thanks

Comment: Check your mail server logs.

Comment: nothing in the maillog file

Comment: Your debug log shows that it is connecting to some host at 68.169.63.242 that self-identifies as www.mbepapers.org. Is this your server? If so, there will be log entries relating to the authentication failure. If not, you need to contact whoever runs the server.

Answer (score 0):

Well this is definitely embarrassing.
When I setup the new server, I didn't setup my mail servers domain name, which is one of the causes for this error.

535 Incorrect authentication data

After adding a mail domain through the control panel, it started working as expected...